# why does seaborn Heatmap shows white rows and columns?

Tags: python, seaborn, data-science, heatmap, data-processing

I'm trying to do an Exercice on Kaggle: [Exercice link](https://www.kaggle.com/dongeorge/beer-consumption-sao-paulo)

I made some Data processing and then tried to plot a heatmap using the seaborn Library but for some reason the heatmap shows a white row and column. here is the Image of the Heatmap. It is not clearly visible here but you can see the white row and column for the Year Feature [image]

here is the Code I'm using. it's actually simple that's why I don't think that this is happening because of an Error in the Code:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('/content/Consumo_cerveja.csv')
# rename the columns to english

dataset.columns = ['Date', 'MediumTemperature', 'MinimumTemperature', 'MaximumTemperature', 'Precipitation', 'Weekend', 'BeerConsumption' ]
dataset['parsed_date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset['Date'], format= '%Y-%m-%d')
dataset.drop('Date', inplace=True, axis=1)
dataset = dataset[0:365]   # resize the dataset to get rid of null rows
datetime_column = dataset.pop('parsed_date')
dataset['Day'] = datetime_column.dt.day
dataset['Month'] = datetime_column.dt.month
dataset['Year'] = datetime_column.dt.year


cor_mat = dataset.corr()   # get the correlation matrix
h_map = sns.heatmap(data=cor_mat, annot=True, cmap='RdYlGn')
```

the original dataset can be found on Kaggle, I posted a link above, but I made some processing so that now I have those Features:

```
 Index(['MediumTemperature', 'MinimumTemperature', 'MaximumTemperature',
       'Precipitation', 'Weekend', 'BeerConsumption', 'Day', 'Month', 'Year'],
      dtype='object')
```

I only split the Date Feature into a separate year, month and day and then I plotted the Heatmap. maybe someone had this Problem before and can tell me why is this happening, I also find a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19639575/r-why-heatmap-shows-white-color-for-rows-with-equal-number)
in R but I didn't understand the answers because I have no Knowledge of R. I hope someone have an answer to this in Python.

Comment: Please see [mcve]. The columns you have are not the ones from the dataset you link to.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Ok I edited my question and supplied the full Code

Comment: Ok, what would you say should the correlation between year and one of the other data be, given that all data is from a single year?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I don't know. I didnt expected to give a white row and white column

Comment: Why would you not expect that? Is the question how to change the color of undefined values in a heatmap?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yes i mean I set a specific color as an argument and the result I get is not the color i set so I thought that it is an error since it is white

Comment: You haven't set any specific color for bad values. But you can do so if you want. `cmap = plt.get_cmap('RdYlGn'); cmap.set_bad("lightblue"); sns.heatmap(...., cmap=cmap)`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest very Nice Thanks! I didn't know I could do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so it appeared to be showing that white color because I didn't set any color for bad values.
Thanks to [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest) I changed the Code and gave a color value so if there is a bad Value the color set for that case will appear on the photo.
before plotting the Heatmap I must add this Code for setting the color:

```
color = plt.get_cmap('RdYlGn')   # default color
color.set_bad('lightblue')    # if the value is bad the color would be lightblue instead of white
h_map = sns.heatmap(data=cor_mat, annot=True, cmap=color)   # now plot the heatmap
```